# Regex Get path name from full path

Tags: regex

can anyone give me a few examples of getting the path from a full path..e.g

c:\aaa\bbb\c cc\file.exe

to

c:\aaa\bbb\c cc\

more than 1 example method would be cool but must be regex only, this is for a language called ICI but it has similar regex to perl and other such language this is why I need a few examples, atleast one will work better than the other and i can modify it.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example of an inverse regex (finds the filename). Just use the substring before the start to get the path.

```
[\w]*[.][\w]*$
```

And the path only:

```
.*[\\]
```

Answer (score 1):

Group (1) will give you `c:\aaa\bbb\c cc` with this

```
(.*)\\\w*\.
```

You can use

```
(.*\\)\w*\.
```

if you want to capture the last `\`

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern it will help full

```
[^\\]+\\
```